# Prestashop 1.7.2.2 new modules folders have 777 permissions

Tags: file-permissions, prestashop-1.7

I have Prestashop 1.7.2.2 installed and for each new module I install through admin dashboard I have the following issue:

Folders and files created for this new module have permissions set 777 for folders and 666 for files and I have to manually change them to 755 for folders and 644 for files in order to properly use that module.

Does anybody know which is the root of this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: what if  you change your `umask` default value ?

Comment: I don't know Prestashop at all but I'm fairly sure there's something wrong with your environment.

Comment: @Abdelouahab how can I do that? I have the website hosted on a shared server

Comment: sorry for the delay, @iBug gave the way fix, now about the file availability, you need to check with the provider

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your shell RC (or `umask` settings). Depending on your shell it may be `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or so. Add this line at its bottom
if you want 0755 to be the default permission for folders and 0644 for files:

```
umask 0022
```

You're likely experiencing this because your current `umask` is set to `0000`. Type `umask` without any arguments to see its current value.

Comment: I have a hosting account on a shared server and I don't have access to shell. I will try to ask hosting company for support then. I thought that the problem is with Prestashop because I had Prestashop 1.6 on the same account and I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: @user3774485 According to my personal experience, it's impossible for a production software to have such a huge bug (file mode), as well as the fact that all these issues I've seen are related to umask settings. It may not be a shell, however.